# capstone disassembler - disassembling single function without knowing length

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly, capstone

I am interested in using the capstone disassembler library.

```
https://github.com/aquynh/capstone
```

My motivation for using this is that I need to be able to disassemble functions at run-time while my program runs.

I have been able to integrate this into my c++ project successfully.  However, I have been unable to figure out how to disassemble an entire function.  I looked through all the examples in the following link.

```
https://github.com/aquynh/capstone/tree/master/tests
```

All the examples take some arbitrary length to disassemble.  I do not know the size of the function that I want to disassemble before hand.  All I know is the symbol name (e.g. "mkdir").  If someone can provide a link to some example that accomplishes what I need, that'd be greatly appreciated.

In case it matters, the architectures that I would like to disassemble for are x86, x86_64, arm and arm64.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it, there just no such thing as "function length" stored anywhere in executable file. I suggest disassembling by small chunks until you encounter a sort of terminator instruction (like "ret").

Comment: I wonder if this is how gdb and lldb does it. I know you can disassemble a function in the debugged

Comment: gdb works by finding the next symbol defined in the executable after the function (entry) and disassembling up to that.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDodd.  I might be able to utilize a similar mechanism.  I'll explore this option.